# Delete Trailing Commas From subset of all sets for a given number

Tags: java

I need to Write a  Java program to  list all the subsets of   the set {1,2,..,n}. Input to your program will be   a  positive integer n and the output will be   a list of the subsets of the set {1,2,....,n}.

I can get it to print out the correct subsets but i always have a trailing comma {1,2,....,n,} and I can't figure out how to remove it. Any help is great! Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //initialize array
        int[] setArray;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Gets Set number from user
        System.out.print("Given Positive Number: ");
        String stringChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        int choice;
        while (true) {
            try {
                //makes sure user's choice is a number within the limits
                choice = Integer.parseInt(stringChoice);
                if (choice >=0) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // do nothing.
            }
            System.out.print("Enter valid option: ");
            stringChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        }


        System.out.println("All Given Subsets: \n");
        //Set's array size to the number that the  user inputed
        setArray = new int[choice];
        //fills array from 1 to the number that the user inputed
        for (int i=choice; i>0; i--){
            setArray[i-1]=i;
        }

        //Calls Print All Subset function
        printAllSubsets(setArray);


        keyboard.close();
    }


        // Print all subsets of given set[]
        static void printAllSubsets(int setArray[]){
            int n = setArray.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++){
                System.out.print("{ ");

                // Print current subset
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){

                    // (1<<j) is a number with jth bit 1
                    // so when we 'and' them with the
                    // subset number we get which numbers
                    // are present in the subset and which
                    // are not
                    if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0){
                        System.out.print(setArray[j] + " , ");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("}");

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Only print the number the first time, then print the comma followed by the number the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`.endsWith(String regex)` and `.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)` are your friends here.

```
String str = "Trailing, comma, example,";
        if(str.endsWith(",")){
            str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

or if you don't want to change the contents of your String...

```
if (str.endsWith(",")) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
    } else {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```